# it is showing "unable to parse/invalid Boolean" error for system metrics

Tags: input, plugins, configuration, fluentd, metricbeat

I am trying to collect system metrics which is in default system module using metrcibeat.it is successfully collected. And those collected are shipped to `fluentd` using `fluentbit`. But when I try to run `fluentd, it is showing "unable to parse/invalid Boolean" error for system metrics.

How do I configure fluentd to resolve this error?

Comment: Please add your configuration, the relevant fluentd logs, and the sample log that you're trying to parse.